# bootstrap li links not working on the server

Tags: php, jquery

menu REPORT is not working (links) while TOOLS and other dropdown menus are working (moving to other pages). why is the REPORT menu is working locally but not on the ubuntu server?

both of them uses the same structure but looks different because in styling

ADDITIONAL:

when you click the li tag, example: BY TYPE . it will go to rep_handle.php. then from rep_handle.php it will move to another location with stat_type VARIABLE to date_handler.php. but it just stop to stat_type.php.

does it has conflict with my CSS? please advise.. thanks

**REPORT**

```
<a class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown" href = "#"> Reports </a>
<ul class = "dropdown-menu">
    <li class="library">
        <a class = "dropdown-toggle" href = "#"> Library </a>
    </li>
    <li class="libraryli divider" style=""></li>
    <li class="libraryli dropdown-submenu" style="">
        <a class = "dropdown-toggle" href = "#">&emsp;&emsp;&bull; Yearly </a>
            <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href = "rep_handler.php?stat_type=type"> By Type</a></li>
                <li><a href = "rep_handler.php?stat_type=cluster"> By <?php echo $CS; ?></a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="libraryli dropdown-submenu" style="">
        <a class = "dropdown-toggle" href = "#">&emsp;&emsp;&bull; TRW </a>
            <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href = "rep_handler.php?stat_type=top">Top Visitors</a></li>
                <li><a href = "rep_handler.php?stat_type=section"> By Section</a></li>
                <li><a href = "rep_handler.php?stat_type=ttype">Comparison By Type</a></li>
                <li><a href = "rep_handler.php?stat_type=tcluster"> Comparison By <?php echo $CS; ?></a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="libraryli divider" style="display:none;"></li>
    <li><a href = "rep_handler.php?stat_type=sydays"> Service Days</a></li>
    <li><a href = "rep_handler.php?stat_type=record"> Records</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.dropdown-toggle').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.dropdown-submenu a.dropdown-toggle').not(this).next('ul').hide();
  });
});
</script>   
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.library').on("mouseover", function(e){
    $(this).siblings('.libraryli').show();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $('span.caret-pr').addClass("caret-reversed");
  });
  $('.library').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).siblings('.libraryli').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $('span.caret-pr').toggleClass("caret-reversed");
  });
});
</script>
```

**CSS**

.dropdown-submenu 
    {
        position: relative;
    }

```
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu 
{
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu 
{
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after 
{
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4.5px 0 4.5px 4.5px;
    border-left-color: #000;
    margin-top: 4.5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after 
{
    border-left-color: #000;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left 
{
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu 
{
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}

.caret-pr
{
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    border-top: 5px solid ;
}

.caret.caret-reversed 
{
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid ;
}

.libraryli
{
background-color:#f5f5f5;
}

</style>
```

Comment: `$ is not defined` usually means u never include jquery? have u included all necessary js?

Comment: maybe i just tested it on firefox with one page only.yes it has JS files in the page. but when the whole website is running from the server, the menu part doesnt got to rep_handler.php and move to Location:rep_date.php (inside rep_handler.php)